# Async function freezes ui

Tags: javascript

I want to have a loading screen where the current state is displayed while resources are loading in the background. Therefore I use an async function. I don't know much about async in JavaScript but in C# and I want to use it the same way so I just call the function.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// main.js
async function loadAssets() {
    var loadingInfo = document.getElementById("loading-info");
    loadingInfo.innerHTML = "Loading entity data..."
    entityDB = JSON.parse(FileReader.read("https://my-domain.com/data/entity-db.json"));
    loadingInfo.innerHTML = "Done...";
}

// file_reader.js
class FileReader {
    static read(fileName) {
        try {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", fileName, false);
            xmlhttp.send();

            if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
                return xmlhttp.responseText;

            return null;
        } catch (error) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I never see the loading text. The UI freezes for 4 seconds and then the text Done is displayed. Am I misunderstanding async in JavaScript?

Comment: [FileReader is a built-in class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader); giving your class the same name is going to confuse maintainers (probably including the you of 6 months in the future).

Answer (score 2):

The `async` keyword has two effects:

- It makes the function return a promise
- It allows you to use the `await` keyword inside it to cause it to go to sleep while it waits for a promise to resolve

**It doesn't make blocking code run asynchronously.**

You have no asynchronous code. Normally `XMLHttpRequest` does run asynchronously but you passed `false` as the third argument to `open()` triggering the *deprecated* synchronous mode.

---

If you want to make an HTTP request asynchronously and deal with the results using promises then you can:

- [Use the fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) which uses promises natively
- [Convert the `load` event handler callback to a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) on the XHR object (while *not* forcing it to run in the synchronous mode)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `fetch` that can be awaited and extract JSON data.
Also forcing an asynchronous operation to become synchronous is always a bad idea. You should embrace asynchronism and learn how to work with it, instead of freezing your code execution.

```
class FileReader {
    static async read(fileName) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(fileName);
            const data = await response.json();
            return data
        } catch (error) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}


async function loadAssets() {
    const loadingInfo = document.getElementById("loading-info");
    loadingInfo.innerHTML = "Loading entity data..."
    const entityDB = await FileReader.read("https://my-domain.com/data/entity-db.json");
    loadingInfo.innerHTML = "Done...";
}
```

Comment: "It should be new FileREader().read(...)" — No, it is implemented with the `static` keyword so it is a property of the class, not of instances.

Comment: Ha thanks, I actually never knew what `static` was. That's very useful to know. I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @Quentin Edited, do you think the code is better now?

Comment: Yes (in so far as it can be made better while keeping the OP's use of a static method as a simple wrapper function).

Comment: Oh yes, keeping OP's structure. I wouldn't use a Class just to wrap a `fetch` call either, a simple helper function would do.